# Why isn't this routing properly using friendly url slug style via htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis, iis-7

My current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myproject/

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ $1.php [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /index.php?r=$1 [QSA]
```

If I write:

**/?r=page1 (Page1 is just an example in this context). : WORKS**

**/page1 : DOESN'T WORK, DISPLAYS 404 ERROR**

What's wrong with my .htaccess?

Comment: Is that your entire .htaccess file?

Comment: @Anonymous I added the entire .htaccess file. Thanks for asking.

Comment: And are you visiting `/myproject/page1`?

Comment: @Anonymous /myproject/index.php, I pass like this, localhost/myproject/?r=page1 (this one works), however, if I do localhost/myproject/page1 it fails and 404 is thrown by IIS.

Comment: Which folder is your .htaccess file in? The root folder?

Comment: @Anonymous it is under /myproject/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83662/discussion-between-n000b101-and-anonymous).

Comment: Yeah, I've just tested this and it's working fine.

If you're not getting anything rewritten at all, check your file permissions, your file name, and ensure that the .htaccess file is in the root of your website.

Comment: RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ index.php?r=$1 [QSA]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line solved it:

```
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ index.php?r=$1 [QSA]
```